# Test exceptions using espec in Elixir app

Tags: unit-testing, testing, elixir

I'm just started to learn Elixir.
I'm trying to test exception with espec (https://github.com/antonmi/espec) and I stucked.

Here is my function

```erlang
defp call_xml(request_body) do
 resp = HTTPotion.post("http://foo.bar", [body: request_body, headers: ["Content-Type": "text/xml"]])
 if resp.status_code in [200, 201] do
  {:ok, elem(XMLRPC.decode(resp.body), 1).param}
 else
  raise AbpError, message: "Message body"
 end
end

def create_some_stuff(a, b, c) do
 req = %XMLRPC.MethodCall{method_name: "Foo.Bar",
                          params:[a, b, c]} |> XMLPRC.encode!
 call_xml(req)
end

# tests

use ESpec
use HyperMock
import :meck

context "when exception rised" do
 it "returns err message" do
   # stubbed with :meck
   expect(MyModule, : create_some_stuff, fn("foo", "bar", "baz") -> raise CustomError end)
   expect(MyModule. create_some_stuff("foo", "bar", "baz")).to eq("???")
 end # it
end
```

In that case I'm getting error raised in my expectation

```erlang
    ** (AbpError) Error occured!
spec/lib/ex_abpclient_spec.exs:135: anonymous fn/7 in ExAbpclientSpec.example_returns_created_payback_eqcpjlrszudikwyovtmxbgfnha/1
(ex_abpclient) ExAbpclient.create_payment_payback("tr-TR", 10966, 10, "R", 495, 10, "DESC")
spec/lib/ex_abpclient_spec.exs:136: ExAbpclientSpec.example_returns_created_payback_eqcpjlrszudikwyovtmxbgfnha/1
(espec) lib/espec/example_runner.ex:33: ESpec.ExampleRunner.run_example/2
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1088: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1088: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
(espec) lib/espec/runner.ex:70: ESpec.Runner.run_examples/1
(espec) lib/espec/runner.ex:43: ESpec.Runner.do_run/2
```

How can I get stubbed exception?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I tried to use HyperMock (https://github.com/stevegraham/hypermock) to stub the request, but with no luck too

```erlang
context "when payback created" do
  it "returns created payback" do
    HyperMock.intercept do
      request = %Request{body: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><methodCall>.....",
                         headers: ["Content-Type": "text/xml"],
                         method: :post,
                         uri: "http://foo.bar/webApiXmlRpcServlet"}
      response = %Response{body: "fooooo", status: 500}
      stub_request request, response
      expect MyModule.create_some_stuff("a", "b", "c") |> to(raise_exception AbpError, "fooooo")
    end
  end # it
end # exception
```

Here is the result

```erlang
/Users/retgoat/workspace/offside/ex_abpclient/spec/lib/ex_abpclient_spec.exs:135
** (AbpError) Error: "fooooo"
(ex_abpclient) lib/ex_abpclient.ex:55: ExAbpclient.call_xml/1
spec/lib/ex_abpclient_spec.exs:143: ExAbpclientSpec.example_returns_created_payback_nqfwohpurlvtzskdjxigeybamc/1
(espec) lib/espec/example_runner.ex:33: ESpec.ExampleRunner.run_example/2
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1088: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1088: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
(espec) lib/espec/runner.ex:70: ESpec.Runner.run_examples/1
(espec) lib/espec/runner.ex:43: ESpec.Runner.do_run/2
(espec) lib/espec/runner.ex:28: ESpec.Runner.handle_call/3


10 examples, 1 failures

Finished in 1.28 seconds (0.14s on load, 1.14s on specs)
```

Exception is rised, but I can't test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roman!
You must pass a function to `expect`, not a result of a function call.
So, just wrap `MyModule.create_some_stuff("a", "b", "c")` by `fn -> end` like you do in the ExUnit expample:
`elixir
it "raises exception" do
  expect(fn -> MyModule.create_some_stuff("a", "b", "c") end)
  |> to(raise_exception AbpError, "fooooo")
end`